# Chrome extension css over-writes background css

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am developing a chrome extension.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Extension name",
  "version": "1",
  "description":
    "Does Something",

  "icons":{"32":"icon.png"},
 "permissions": ["tabs", "notifications","<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"],
 "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "web_accessible_resources": [

  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "32":"icon.png"
        },
    "default_popup":"popup.html",
    "default_stylesheet":"popup.css",
    "default_script":"popup.js"

  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="extension">
    <head>
        <title>App Test</title>

        <!-- StyleSheets -->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl as mainVm">

    </body>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="SupportingScripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="SupportingScripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

The popup.css takes over the background css. This too happens selectively only. It does not overwrite every element. For example, it does not change body background color but changes body font.
Which other.css file is overwriting my popup.css ? How to restrict popup.css to the extension popup box only ?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean that the rules of your popup.css are applied to your open tabs?

Comment: `browser_action.default_stylesheet` is not a thing.